Running makefile on Windows cannot find the file specified
I'm trying to run a makefile on my Windows 11 computer and running into errors. Here are the file contents (this is from a package that requires permission to use so I erased the file names -- I don't know whether this is standard, and I can add the names back if that is required and typically not an issue):
CC = gcc
MPICC = mpicc
CFLAGS = -O3
LDFLAGS = -Wl,-R,\.
LIBS = -lm
UNAME_S = $(shell uname -s)

ifneq (, $(findstring SunOS, $(UNAME_S)))
    LIBS += -lnsl -lsocket -lresolv
endif

compile:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o ___.exe ___.c ___.c ___.c $(LIBS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o ___.exe ___.c ___.c ___.c $(LIBS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o ___.exe ___.c ___.c ___.c $(LIBS)

compile-parallel:
    $(MPICC) $(CFLAGS) -o ___.exe ___.c ___.c ___.c $(LIBS)
    $(MPICC) $(CFLAGS) -shared -fPIC -o ___.so ___.c ___.c $(LIBS)

ifneq ("$(wildcard borgmm.*)","")
    $(MPICC) $(CFLAGS) -o ___.exe ___.c ___.c ___.c $(LIBS)
    $(MPICC) $(CFLAGS) -shared -fPIC -o ___.so ___.c ___.c $(LIBS)
endif

.PHONY: compile, compile-parallel

When I run it, I get an error at the first line under "compile:".
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, gcc -O3 -o ___.exe ___.c borg.c ___.c -lm, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.

All of the files other than ___.exe (which is being created by this line if I understand correctly) are in the same folder as the makefile. I get this error both when running with make installed by Chocolatey in both Command Prompt and Powershell, and the same error appears in the VSCode developer command prompt. I have never edited a makefile before and am not sure what's happening inside. Any help would be very appreciated!

This means that you don't have a program named gcc installed on your system.  GCC is the GNU Compiler.  It doesn't come with Windows, so if you want to use it you'll have to install it yourself.  Else, you need to change the CC variable to contain whatever C compiler you have access to.

You might also need to install an MPI implementation, and possibly adjust the value of MPICC, too.  And there may be other issues.  There are perfectly good make implementations for Windows, but many makefiles you might try to use with them make assumptions about the operating environment that are not remotely satisfied by a typical Windows shell and execution environment.

Can you run gcc from the cmd prompt?  Powershell won't look in the current directory for commands, just in the PATH.

Thank you all so much for your help! I installed gcc with "choco instal mingw" and the make file is now working (I do still get "process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, uname -s, ...) failed." though, but the other lines work). @MadScientist Could you please make your comment an answer so I can accept it?

uname is also a POSIX program, that isn't available on Windows.  In general if you are trying to build software intended for POSIX-based platforms like Linux and MacOS, on Windows, you will have to do some amount of hacking to get it working.
